# Invalid input syntax for type interval Error

Tags: postgresql-10

When i add a day to a date in postgres as below

```
SELECT '2018-08-20 00:00:00.0' + INTERVAL '1 DAY';
```

Getting below exception in pgAdmin4. Can any one help me here.

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "2018-08-20 00:00:00.0"
LINE 1: SELECT '2018-08-20 00:00:00.0' - INTERVAL '1 DAY';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date '2018-08-20 00:00:00.0' - INTERVAL '1 DAY';
```

Solved the problem.